What is an introductory book or resource for qiskit?
I am a complete beginner to qiskit, I know some stuff about quantum computing (I read a book on quantum computing by David McMahon), so now I want to learn to use qiskit, I tried to follow the recent tutorials on IBM Quantum channel (Coding with Qiskit 1.0.x), but I don't understand most of the stuff he is talking about. Like what does Estimator do, etc.. So how should I approach it, should I read its full documentation or rather is there any book on it, or would you recommend something else? I just completed my first year undergrad

I would suggest you start learning about the basics of quantum information and quantum circuits. These lessons also introduce basic qiskit programs. Then after this go through the next chapter on quantum algorithms. After this I suggest you to take the practice tests at the end of these chapters to solidify the foundations of what you learnt.
Now to learn qiskit in detail, I started from the online documentation found here. I would recommend you to start going through the section step-by-step, which means you start from the section called "Start" and then move on to next section "Build" followed by "Transpile", "Verify", and "Run". These sections describe in great detail all the ways on how you can write a code in qiskit and how you can transpile the code to match the attributes of the real quantum system that you want to run your code on. If you prefer, you can look at all the tutorials on various topics found here.
